# Express vector field $V$ in form $\sum v_iU_i$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Express the given vector field $V$ in the standard form $\sum v_iU_i$

($V$ vector field is a function that assigns to each point $p$ of $\Bbb{R^3}$ a tangent vector $V(p)$ to $\Bbb{R^3}$ at $p$)

At each point p $V(p)$ is the vector from the point $(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ to the point $(1+p_1,p_2.p_3,p_2)$

Should I take $V(p)$ as $(1+p_1,p_2p_3,p_2)$ or $( 1,p_2.p_3 - p_2,p_2-p_3)$??

Comment: What is the vector between the points $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{R}^3$ and $(d,e,f)\in\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: Sure (d,e,f)-(a,b,c) but it is not any vector it is tangent vector. E.g. If p = (1,1,3) is application point and v=(2,3,1) then the tangent vector Vp is (3,4,5) which is summation of 2 vectors. I have confused because of that

Comment: I understand your confusion. Basically the application point does not matter here, as the tangent space to $\mathbb{R}^3$ is canonically isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^3$. So the second thing you wrote down is your vector. I am inclined to say 'don't worry about this now, but wait until you study differential geometry, and it will all make more sense'.

Comment: @B.Pasternak Very thanks for your concern. Is answer U1 + y(z-1)U2 + (y-z)U3 ?

Comment: That seems correct to me, as long as by $U_i$ you mean the $i$-th basis vector, i.e. $U_1=(1,0,0)$ etc..

Comment: @B.Pasternak yes basis vector. Thanks again